# How do you send the "ESC" key in OS X using osascript

Tags: macos, applescript, osascript

I'd like to create a small script using osascript in Mac OS X Snow Leopard to emulate pressing the Escape key on the keyboard. How is this most easily done?

Answer (score 2):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 53'
```